# Passing a string to a structure

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a list of cars in a file where the lines are of the form

```
car_1_name [car_1_id] & car_2_name [car_2_id]
```

I want to store the names and ids of each car in an anrray. For this purpose I have created two structures called "_Car_" and "_Car_List_". However, the function "parse" that I wrote for parsing lines of the form above does not seem to extract the names of the car properly (I use strtok to split the string up). However, when I add a car manually to the list the string gets displayed correctly. Below you can find my minimum working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _Car_
{
  char* name_;
  int id_;
  struct _Car_* parent_1_;
  struct _Car_* parent_2_;
};

struct _Car_List_
{
  struct _Car_* car_list[100];
  int number_of_cars;
};


struct _Car_* createCar(char* name, int id)
{
  struct _Car_* car = malloc(sizeof(struct _Car_));

  if (car == NULL)
    return NULL;

  car -> name_ = name;
  car -> id_ = id;

  return car;
}

void addCar(struct _Car_List_* my_list, struct _Car_* car)
{
  my_list -> car_list[my_list -> number_of_cars] = car;
  my_list -> number_of_cars = my_list -> number_of_cars + 1;

}

int parse(struct _Car_List_* my_list)
{
  char string[] = "Ferrari [3] & Porsche [6]\n";

  char* car_1_string = strtok(string, "&");
  char* car_2_string = strtok(NULL, "&");

  char* car_1_name = strtok(car_1_string, "[");
  int car_1_id = atoi(strtok(NULL, "]"));

  char* car_2_name = strtok(car_2_string, "[");
  int car_2_id = atoi(strtok(NULL, "]"));

  struct _Car_* car_1 = createCar(car_1_name, car_1_id);
  struct _Car_* car_2 = createCar(car_2_name, car_2_id);

  addCar(my_list, car_1);
  addCar(my_list, car_2);

  return 0;
}

void printList(struct _Car_List_* my_list)
{
  int i = 0;
  struct _Car_* car = my_list -> car_list[i];

  while (car != NULL)
  {
    printf("- %s [%d]\n", car -> name_, car -> id_);
    i = i + 1;
    car = my_list -> car_list[i];
  }
}

int testAdd(struct _Car_List_* my_list)
{
  struct _Car_* car = createCar("Renault", 1);
  addCar(my_list, car);

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  struct _Car_List_* my_list = malloc(sizeof(struct _Car_List_));
  my_list -> number_of_cars = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
    my_list -> car_list[i] = NULL;

  testAdd(my_list);
  parse(my_list);

  printf("Below the printed list:\n");
  printList(my_list);

  return 0;
}
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the program do improperly? Details will help us answer.

Comment: `createCar()` needs to make copies of the name and id strings. Otherwise you're saving pointers to a local string that becomes invalid when the function returns.

Comment: Inside your `struct` you must use memory you control, _owning pointers_ only. Also `strtok` probably is not a good choice for the use here. And the model is confusing: it seems that there is sort of a `node` thing, containing data and pointing to data in `parent_1_` and `parent_2_`, but this is not in the code. Maybe you could revise the model

Comment: You should fix `printList` to use `number_of_cars` to determine where your list ends, rather than looking for a terminating `NULL` pointer.  As it is now, it will index past the end of the array if you ever use all 100 slots.

Comment: Also, instead of writing things like `x->y = x->y + 1;`, just write `x->y++;`  Don't fight the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` does not allocate any new memory. `car_1_name` and `car_2_name` both point at memory inside `string`. `string` is a local variable and will be deallocated when `parse` exits. That memory may then be overwritten leaving `car_1_name` and `car_2_name` pointing at garbage.

You must copy the strtok pointers to new memory, probably with [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup).

Comment: Note that `strdup` is not defined by the C standard (though I think C23 will add it). It is defined by POSIX, and will very likely be available in any C implementation you're using. If not, it's easy enough to create a replacement.